# Why when changing tabs sometimes canvas animation fails?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've created a simple JavaScript canvas animation, and I've noticed that when I change to another tab and then come back to the original tab, sometimes the box stays moving sticked to one border or stays quiet in one corner. It happens in small and big time periods.

I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox latest versions and I don't know what's causing the bug.

Here's the code in jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Pablo_No/d2r4u105/)

And here's a code snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('animation');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var startTime;
      var elapsed;
      var oldTimeStamp;
      var interval;
      function createBox(x, y, width, height, vx, vy, color) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
        this.vx = vx
        this.vy = vy
        this.color = color
        this.draw = function () {
          ctx.fillStyle = this.color
          ctx.fillRect(
            Math.max(Math.min(this.x, canvas.width-this.width), 0),
            Math.max(Math.min(this.y, canvas.height-this.height), 0),
            this.width,
            this.height
          );
        }
      }
      var red = new createBox(0, 0, 50, 75,  0.1, 0.2, "gray")
      function step(timeStamp) {
        // Time
        if (startTime === undefined) {
          startTime = timeStamp
          oldTimeStamp = timeStamp
        }
        elapsed = timeStamp - startTime;
        interval = timeStamp - oldTimeStamp
        if(interval > 150){
          interval = 150
        }
        oldTimeStamp = timeStamp
        // Draw
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (red.y + red.vy > canvas.height-red.height || red.y + red.vy < 0) {
          red.vy = -red.vy;
        }
        if (red.x + red.vx > canvas.width-red.width || red.x + red.vx < 0) {
          red.vx = -red.vx;
        }
        red.x = red.x + red.vx * interval

        red.y = red.y + red.vy * interval
        red.draw()
        // Request new animation frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Canvas2-Bug</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="animation" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

The questions are:

- What's causing the bug
- How can I fix it

#### Edits

1. Udapte question with code from @theusaf that solves one issue which only happens in big time periods. (Changing time period to 150)

Comment: Interesting problem, I can confirm this is an issue

Comment: @BobvanLuijt I think that it's a strange issue too.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is because `requestAnimationFrame` pauses until the user comes back to the tab, creating a large `interval`. This sets `red.x` and `red.y` to very large numbers. Then, the velocity of the box is constantly swapped, meaning that the box stays in the corner.

Ex: user leaves for a time, after the draw, `red.x` and `red.y` are numbers like `500`

`red.x/red.y + red.vx/red.vy` will then always be greater than `canvas.height/width - red.height/width`

- `red.vx/red.vy` then swaps from being negative to positive and back to negative each frame.

To fix this, you can add a condition to make sure that `interval` doesn't get too high (over 50):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('animation');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var startTime;
      var elapsed;
      var oldTimeStamp;
      var interval;
      function createBox(x, y, width, height, vx, vy, color) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
        this.vx = vx
        this.vy = vy
        this.color = color
        this.draw = function () {
          ctx.fillStyle = this.color
          ctx.fillRect(
            Math.max(Math.min(this.x, canvas.width-this.width), 0),
            Math.max(Math.min(this.y, canvas.height-this.height), 0),
            this.width,
            this.height
          );
        }
      }
      var red = new createBox(0, 0, 50, 75,  0.1, 0.2, "gray")
      function step(timeStamp) {
        // Time
        if (startTime === undefined) {
          startTime = timeStamp
          oldTimeStamp = timeStamp
        }
        elapsed = timeStamp - startTime;
        interval = timeStamp - oldTimeStamp;
        if(interval > 50){interval=50}
        oldTimeStamp = timeStamp
        // Draw
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (red.y + red.vy > canvas.height-red.height || red.y + red.vy < 0) {
          red.vy = -red.vy;
        }
        if (red.x + red.vx > canvas.width-red.width || red.x + red.vx < 0) {
          red.vx = -red.vx;
        }
        red.x = red.x + red.vx * interval

        red.y = red.y + red.vy * interval
        red.draw()
        // Request new animation frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Canvas2-Bug</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="animation" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one issue, but the other issue still happens in smaller time periods, I'll udapte the question with your code.